# Orange livebox and ubuntu port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I installed a LAMP server in my computer to try some php and html scripts and I want to know if I can make those files public so I can see them from other computer with other internet conection. My router is the orange livebox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find out to what ports is your apache server listening to (almost always it is port 80)

   ```
   cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf
   ```
2. **Find your local IP address of your server**. Run `ifconfig` in terminal and look after `inet addr:` under your default connection (my default connection is `wlan0`).
3. **Enter your router's web management.** In my case enter `192.168.1.1` in the web browser to access the configuration of the router.
4. **Login** - the default user and password for my router is `admin`.
5. Go to advanced configuration -> NAT -> NAT Mapping Table
6. **Add the IP address of your server** with the port on which your apache server is listening in LAN and Public. Protocol Type: TCP. Click configure. Go to `NAT Mapping Table`. Look for the IP and port you just configured and look for your Pseudo IP. That's your public IP.
7. **Allow incoming traffic**. Go to the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```
8. **Check your website** with `localhost/yourWeb` or on another computer in LAN by entering `your.local.ip/yourWeb` or in the Internet by entering `your.public.ip/yourWeb`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your router type but if you want to view your files from everywhere you have to meet following requirements:

1. **Your router must support [NAT](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)**. If you want to view your files from everywhere you have to reroute all incoming requests (usually on port 80) from the Internet to your server. I have these setting accessible in my router's web management.
2. **You have to have public IP.** If you want to always have the same address where you can see all your files, then you have to have public IP address. This basically means that the IP address assigned to you by your ISP is always the same.

But if you want to view your files only *inside you local area network* you can just enter local IP address of your server to another computer's browser window